# Лимиты на дочерние процессы/потоки в systemd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

Есть скрипт, который подготавливает работу софта и запускает его, софт многопоточный. Если запускаю напрямую скрипт, то работает все стабильно. Но мне нужно, что бы он постоянно крутился на сервере, потому создаю сервис через systemd, который запускает этот скрипт, запускается нормально, но только через systemd софт падает когда пытается создать в общей сложности больше ~4к потоков, при том, что если из консоли запустить скрипт, то софт нормально работает с большим количеством потоков. Получается, что есть какие-то ограничение, которые нужно повысить для systemd, так думаю, перебрал всё, что смог найти, ничего не помогло, да и в целом не до конца уверен, что иду в том направлении, опыта в этом почти нет.

Сервер на котором запускаю: Ubuntu 18.04

Пробовал убрать лимиты, если это то:

```
~# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 128329
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 128329
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Файл, который создаю:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root

Type=simple
TimeoutSec=0

LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
DefaultLimitMEMLOCK=infinity
MemoryLimit=30G

WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html
Environment="TERM=linux" 'TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/php7.2 -f /var/www/html/main.php > logs/log.txt 2> logs/errors.txt


Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

UPD: Решил проблему добавлением настройки:

```
[Service]
TasksMax=100000
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло добавление настройки:

```
[Service]
TasksMax=100000
```